# How to always resolve a domain name to a fixed IP without rooting?

Tags: dns, hosts

The financial website `https://wex1.in` got it’s domain name deleted but it’s still possible to reach it by adding `104.25.31.35 wex1.in` to etc/hosts files on a ᴘᴄ.

So how to access the website without editing `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: You need some DNS server that has this record.

Comment: @iBug I’m talking about a public website. So this isn’t possible.

Comment: Then you're out of luck

Comment: @iBug many users like me ended up trusting such website which had no problem between 2011 and 2017. So this a question worthing more than 100 million (literally) with more than 8000 for me.

Comment: I agree. I don't have time to write a detailed answer now, but with my experience and expertise I don't think it's possible without editing `/etc/hosts`, as said in your question.

Comment: @iBug and the answer isn’t for me but for authorities. So for more than 100 millions in money combined, `you're out of luck` is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options you can go with:

- **Enter IP address** directly (with port `80` or `443`) to web browser's address bar instead of domain name. But this won't work if web server relies on `host` header or [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) for virtually hosting multiple websites on same IP address.
- It's possible to use VpnService API of Android to capture all DNS traffic without rooting phone. That's how apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone) and [this](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/ADBLOCKING.md) work. Then the **VPN app may use a custom `hosts` file** before making queries to configured upstream DNS server. [Virtual Hosts](https://github.com/x-falcon/Virtual-Hosts/releases/) is an open-source app to achieve this.
- As suggested by @[iBug](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/205764/ibug), you can setup a **DNS server** (locally or on cloud) and [configure your phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526) to use that for DNS queries. For instance if using `dnsmasq`, add `address=/wex1.in/104.25.31.35` to *“dnsmasq.conf”*. Or on `dnscrypt-proxy` add `wex1.in 104.25.31.35` to *“cloaking-rules.txt”*.
  Similarly other DNS servers can be configured to return a predefined IP address for a specific name.
- Configure phone to use a [**proxy**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526) or **VPN** and then add the entry `104.25.31.35 wex1.in` in `hosts` file on proxy server or run a local DNS server on VPN server.
- If you don't want to root the device but bootloader is unlocked (or possible to unlock) and a custom recovery is available, mount `/system` in recovery and **edit `hosts` file** there. Set proper permissions; ownership, mode and SELinux label.

  If you don't want to modify `/system` partition (e.g. to not break `dm-verity` or OTAs), it's possible to bind mount a custom `hosts` file from somewhere on `/data`. But that would require some extra effort like defining an `init` service, modifying SELinux policy etc.

Make sure not to use Private DNS (on Android 9+) so that DNS queries always go on port `53` unencrypted.

**PS:** Same methods can be used to block ads without rooting phone.