# How does Android do DNS name resolution?

Tags: dns

I am learning about how Windows does name resolution and need to know how Android does it so an app will work on my Windows laptop and from my Android Phone.

Borrowing from a post on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine/508057), the [normal resolution method on Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order) is as follows:

> 1. The client checks to see if the name queried is its own.
> 2. The client then searches a local Hosts file, a list of IP address and names stored on the local computer.
> 3. Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried.
> 4. If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution sequence is used as a backup. This order can be changed by configuring the NetBIOS node type of the client.

I use `dnsmasq` to provide local DNS resolution so I can map my own made up hostnames to local LAN IP addresses. This also allows me to see, in the `dnsmasq` log file, the DNS query that goes from the client to the DNS server. While testing the website from my phone I could swear using the URL address `http://mywebsite` in a Chrome browser on the phone was loading the website and the `dnsmasq` log showed just that unqualified name - `mywebsite` - resolving to the desired local IP address the web server is at.

However that was a few days ago, now the `dnsmasq` log always shows that the DHCP server DNS suffix [home] has been appended. So I see `mywebsite.home` in the `dnsmasq` log even though I used the URL address `http://mywebsite` in the phones Chrome browser. I didn't change anything with the phone. It is still set up to get its IP address via DHCP, in practice it never changes.

So my questions are:

1. How does Android OS resolve domain names to IP addresses - what things does it try and in what order?
2. Any feedback on why Android seemed to be resolving the unqualified hostname in my browser originally without any DNS suffix being appended. But now the `[home]` suffix is always appended as reported in the `dnsmasq` log file.

**Update 1**

After some more testing I have again seen the scenario where the webpage `http://mymovies` loads from the Android phone but the `dnsmasq` log appears to show the name resolution happening on an unqualified domain name (bare hostname: `mymovies`).

[image]

The `x`'s are my redacted routers public IP address.

Can anyone explain what `dnsmasq` is doing here?

Starting from 02:07:22 it initially seems to try resolving the name `mymovies.home`. This makes sense because the phones IP is dynamically allocated by the DHCP server and I can see on my laptop that the DHCP server sends the DNS suffix `[home]` as the connection-specific DNS suffix so it must be doing the same to the phone I guess?

The reason why it fails here is because I do not have an entry for `mymovies.home` in `dnsmasq.conf` - I commented it out. I DO have an address entry for `mymovies` in `dnsmasq.conf` and that seems to be why it can resolve `mymovies` to an IP address.
Is this a difference of name resolution in Android compared with Windows - that eventually Android OS WILL try to resolve an unqualified domain name (bare hostname) to an IP address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How DNS queries made by a program are being resolved isn't specific to an OS, but depends on the resolver library the program is using. DNS resolvers have traditionally been part of OS's standard C library e.g. [Bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/README.md) on Android, [`libcmt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features) on Windows, `glibc`, `musl`, `dietlibc`, `uClibc` and others on Linux. Not all C libraries use the same approach to resolve host/domain names. While `glibc` and alike provide complicated but highly configurable mechanisms like Name Service Switch, others just rely on `hosts` and DNS queries to upstream nameserver as configured in [`/etc/resolv.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). Android's resolver <sup>([1](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/dns-resolver), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/libc/dns/net/getaddrinfo.c#67))</sup> looks up cache, `hosts` and DNS:

> *"DNS lookups are centralized in the `netd` daemon to allow for system-wide caching, while apps call functions (such as `getaddrinfo`) in Bionic. The query is sent over a UNIX socket to `/dev/socket/dnsproxyd` to the `netd` daemon, which parses the request and calls `getaddrinfo` again to issue DNS lookups, then caches the results so that other apps can use them."*

DNS server address is either received through PDP context on Mobile Data or through DHCP on Wi-Fi (also possibly to [set manually](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205775/218526)) or the hard-coded value `8.8.8.8` is used. Since Android 9 Private DNS (DNS over TLS) may also be configured in Settings. It's also possible to set DNS and domain name using `ndc resolver setnetdns` command. See more details in [How to configure DNS properly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526).

> `dnsmasq` log always shows that the DHCP server `DNS` suffix [home] has been appended

`.home` suffix is being provided by your DHCP server (router?) to Android as part of DHCP request (code 15). Android's DHCP client [asks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpClient.java#153) server for [option 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.8) (domain name server) and [option 15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.17) (domain name), which are then forwarded to C library ([_resolv_set_nameservers_for_net](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/libc/dns/resolv/res_cache.c#2001)) through [DnsManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/DnsManager.java#356), [NetworkManagementService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/services/core/java/com/android/server/NetworkManagementService.java#1946) and [`netd`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/server/ResolverController.cpp#478).

On Linux DHCP client (e.g. `dhcpcd`) modifies `resolv.conf` itself or uses a program like [`resolvconf`](https://roy.marples.name/projects/openresolv) which is dedicated to manage `resolv.conf`. `nameserver` keyword defines DNS server and `search` defines search list for host-name lookup (DHCP [option 119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3397#section-2) or 15). Android uses default values hard-coded in different [header files](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/libc/dns/include/) other than those received from DHCP or set manually.

Windows's DHCP client and DNS resolver support option 15. Additional configurations which are honored by DNS Client service (`dnscache`) and library can be made through Network Connections or Group Policy Editor or Registry Editor.

> Is this a difference of name resolution in Android compared with Windows - that eventually Android OS WILL try to resolve an unqualified domain name (bare hostname) to an IP address?

As far as I have seen this is almost standard behavior for Linux libc's. [Android's DNS resolver code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/libc/dns/resolv) is also based on NetBSD - another Linux-like operating system. A single-label unqualified name is first tried with DNS suffix appended, then tried without suffix 4 times (see *"options attempts:n"* for `resolv.conf`). For multi-label name the order is reversed while a FQDN (with trailing `.`) is never tried with suffix. On Windows you can append dot to unqualified name so that it's treated as FQDN. It's possible to set it as default behavior by adding dot (`.`) to "[DNS suffix for this connection](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2455390&seqNum=3)". See also for [Multi-Label Name Queries](https://computerstepbystep.com/allow-dns-suffix-appending-to-unqualified-multi-label-name-queries.html).

> I am learning about how Windows does name resolution and need to know how Android does it

As stated in the start, name resolution might not be persistent across whole OS. On Android, for instance, Firefox or Chrome will be depending on Bionic resolver while some `busybox ping` (or even some native libraries included with GUI apps) will be trying to read `resolv.conf` and make DNS queries directly.
Also network troubleshooting tools like `ping` and `getent` rely on OS's internal resolver libraries like NSS, while DNS diagnostic tools like `nslookup`, `dig` and `host` act as independent DNS clients - they don't read `hosts` file and may not honor `resolv.conf` in its entirety. `dig` provides commandline arguments to (not) use options set in `resolv.conf`, and similarly [Windows `nslookup` has its own built-in resolver](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2013/02/17/nslookup-suffixing-behavior/).

So even on same OS you can't expect same DNS resolution behavior when using different GUI/CLI programs because they could be using different libc and/or different resolver and/or different configuration.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to ping a local network host by hostname?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215878/218526)

Comment: Irfan.. thank you so much for this detailed answer. I can now see how DNS lookups are influenced by many factors. Interesting that Windows will not do a DNS lookup on a bare hostname but Android will due to different DNS resolver code. Cheers.

Comment: For reference: [Starting from November 2021, Android resolver supports mDNS .local resolution](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/modular-system/dns-resolver#mdns-local-resolution).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain what `dnsmasq` is doing here?

- query[A] = resolution request for IPv4
- From: obviously the source, as you already stated, your router's public address.
- forwarded to: is the URL forwarding to the DNS servers that you configured for such kind of URLs, in case that no config there, is using the default DNS servers or your GW.
- reply: the DNS Server is not being able to resolve the host because that domain doesn't exist (mymovies.home) and therefore is delivering that "NXDOMAIN" as reply
- 192.168.1.124 is the IP that you have statically configured for mymovies